# Material UI: How to vertically centre align an icon button?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have this tsx piece of code to show a text box and an icon button to add something:

```
<TextField id="outlined-basic" label="22Keyword" defaultValue={"test123"} variant="outlined" />
            <IconButton aria-label="delete">
                <AddCircleOutlineOutlinedIcon />
            </IconButton>
```

The output is like this:
[image]

As you can see, the "+" icon is not vertically aligned with middle of the textbox. I tried adding padding to the button but it ruins the circle that is shown when mouse is hovering and makes it like an oval:

```
<TextField id="outlined-basic" label="22Keyword" defaultValue={"test123"} variant="outlined" />
            <IconButton aria-label="delete" style={{paddingTop: 19}}>
                <AddCircleOutlineOutlinedIcon />
            </IconButton>
```

[image]

How can I say "all of these elements should be aligned"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use [Box](https://mui.com/components/box/) component and [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```
<Box
  display="flex"
  alignItems="center"
>
  <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="22Keyword" defaultValue={"test123"} variant="outlined" />
            <IconButton aria-label="delete">
                <AddCircleOutlineOutlinedIcon />
            </IconButton>
</Box>
```

It supports all [system](https://mui.com/system/properties/) properties.

Comment: yes! Thanks. That works. Although I had to change flexDir from column to row.

Comment: Yes, it should be row and also optional.